# Non-Greedy Regex Match

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

**I'd like to match `if x > 64 then return 0, 0 end` inside this string.**

```
 function if x > 64 then return 0, 0 end return 1, 0 end
```

I'm using `if(.*)then(.*)end`. However, this matches: `if x > 64 then return 0, 0 end return 1, 0 end`, which is one `end` too many.

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
if(.*)then(.*?)end
```

You could add word boundaries to make sure you match `end` as a word, not as a part of a variable name:

```
if(.*)then(.*?)\bend\b
```

To analyse code, you probably should use a parser instead of a regex, though.

Comment: Perfect- thank you.

Comment: Downvoter : constructive criticism is welcome!

Comment: There's not really any reason to down-vote this o.o